# CASE SQL Oracle Query - What is wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have following query to select the view to be used in the query, however I get the error:

> FROM keyword not found where expected

```
select *, (CASE WHEN 'employee' = 'employee' THEN employee ELSE vw END) FROM type1
```

Comment: Don't see any issue though. Which RDBMS are you in?

Comment: It works for me. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32697

Comment: `CASE WHEN 'employee' = 'employee'` seems rather useless.

Comment: this is a sample query to test it.

Comment: supposedly you can not have a table name which is a dynamic using a variable, is this just for Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select type1.*,
      (CASE WHEN 'employee' = 'employee'
            THEN employee 
            ELSE vw 
       END)
FROM type1
```

I always *prefix* with the tablename/table alias to the `*` and it works!!

We just need to specify, fetch `all` the column from `this` table, when we specify combination of wildcard and other select expressions!

Comment: Do you even realize that `'employee' = 'employee'` always evaluates to true?

Comment: Yeah, but it was just a sample query to describe this issue, I presumed!!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar +Plus one.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `*` and individual columns together in select statement.

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN 'employee' = 'employee' THEN 'employee' ELSE 'vw' END)
  FROM  dual
```

Comment: Do you even realize that `'employee' = 'employee'` always evaluates to true?

Comment: @Krumia It is added as demo.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do a `*,` in Oracle without an alias/TableName(.) in front of it. List out the columns you want to see in the result set or add a table alias/tablename.

Comment: I said "*,". I never said you cannot use *

Comment: yeah, I noticed the comma right after posting my comment ;)

Comment: Umm... Yes you can. Try `SELECT t.*, t.column_name FROM table_name t;`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the name of the view the select statement shall retrieve data from in the column list part of the statement.